# Bluetooth LE: send information

Tags: cocoa, ios7, ibeacon

How to send information via Bluetooth LE 4.0 using CLBeacon UUID, major and minor identifiers? 
According to CoreBluetooth documentation the maximal distance is 15 m, but as for iBeacons technology it's ranged up to several tens of meters.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot transfer any data in an iBeacon transmission other than UUID major and minor.  No other fields can be sent and received by apps in iOS.

The range of iBeacon transmissions are basically the same as regular Bluetooth LE transmissions because iBeacon transmissions ARE Bluetooth LE transmissions.

Because iBeacons are one way transmissions they may be more workable at the very end of the range of BLE, because they can still work if 80 percent of packets are lost.

While you could design your own one way BLE transmission using advertisements, an iOS app would not be able to read the encoded fields because iOS disallows access to the raw advertisement data.

Comment: After advertising there's UUID, major, minor. And it's needed to send a picture to the device with the UUID, major, minor. Using other Bluetooth functions how to send data to the peripheral using the UUID? (I am not talking about iBeacon at all now).

Comment: Do not confuse the ProximityUUID sent by an iBeacon peripheral and detectable with CoreLocation with the UUID of a Bluetooth service discoverable by CoreBluetooth.  They are not the same.  You can certainly set up a second data transfer Bluetooth service on the peripheral that also acts as an iBeacon, but it will be completely independent and will not share any UUID.